# rollback a sql table data as yesterday

Tags: sql, database

I have updated a sql table data by mistake. How can I revert back my changes to get the data as yesterday or before the update.

```
select id, number from mytable
```

Comment: You have a backup of the database from before your change?

Comment: What database vendor?

Comment: I don't know whether I have or haven't . I don't want to restore entire database. I need to restore only the table that I updated.

Comment: You are probably out of luck.

Comment: By updated a sql table means did u only insert a new records in tableor di u perform updation on record too? If only insert then u can delete all records from table which were created after a given time. In case of update it is not possible to rollback to any given state/time unless some kind of versioning of data is implemented for your table.

Comment: @PrinithaReddy If you have a  backup, you restore it under a different name, then use the table in that version to repair your real table.

Answer (score 1):

If only you used a transaction to give you the option to roll back.
Sorry that without a transaction, you will need to reset the data from a back up.

For example,

```
BEGIN TRAN T1; UPDATE ImportantStuff SET ImportantValue
```

If its looks good;

```
COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

If it does'nt;

```
ROLLBACK TRAN T1
```